# Comparing Two values from two different Databases not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, comparison

I have two databases that are replication from Home office to location and Location to Home office. (in house built process)

I have been tasked to compare the HO and Loc's data. I have some varchar fields that when looking at the data in a query they appear to match However when i do a comparison HO.Desc = Loc.Desc i get false. I have found that there are returns and some times hidden spaces in one or the other value. I have done Rtrim(ltrim(loc.desc) = rtrim(ltrim(ho.desc) still the same results. Can some one give me some advice on how to do a comparison?

I have tried ltrim(rtrim(value))

I hope to be able to mark the two values as the same.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the code that doesn't work

Comment: Sorry i am using SQL2008

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are a million questions on SO about comparing tables/databases

Answer (score 0):

I have a handy script I use to identify invisible characters; it gives you every character in the string but as a separate row per character.

```
DECLARE @nstring NVARCHAR(1000)

select top 1 @nstring = [Desc]
FROM myTable
WHERE [Desc] LIKE '%Criteria%'

print @nstring

DECLARE @position INT
 SET @position = 1

DECLARE @CharList TABLE (
 Position INT,
 UnicodeChar NVARCHAR(1),
 UnicodeValue INT
 )

WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@nstring)
 BEGIN
 INSERT @CharList
 SELECT @position as Position
 ,CONVERT(nchar(1),SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)) as UnicodeChar
 ,UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)) as UnicodeValue
 SET @position = @position + 1
 END

SELECT * FROM @CharList
```